# JavaEE 6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null

Tags: jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

Yesterday when I was working on my JavaEE application, it was happily getting deployed to Glassfish 3.1 and all the `[web, ejb, jpa]` engines were working and I was able to interact with database without any problem. But ever since I started working today I've been having `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null` error when I try to retrieve something from database. The application is still deploying without any problems but I can't see the `[jpa]` engine working this time. I couldn't figure out why was I getting this error. I did not make any changes to may configuration on the Glassfish Admin Console or anything in my application.

Only thing that I did yesterday was to use the `appclient` (ACC) provided by Glassfish 3.1 to test dependency injection of resources using `@Resource`.

I did absolutely nothing else than that. But today when I deploy my application I do not see the `[jpa]` engine listed with `[web, ejb]` when I see the deployed modules and components on my application on Glassfish admin console.

Could someone help me understand the reason why would it happening and how to solve this problem. I've already spent quite a lot of time trying to get it to work but I cant see the `[jpa]` engine working to give me an `EntityManagerFactory` for my application to talk to database.

**Complete stacktrace**:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2305)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2088)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy206.getAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.transbinary.imdb.service.MovieManagementServiceJpaImpl.getAllMovies(MovieManagementServiceJpaImpl.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at $Proxy271.getAllMovies(Unknown Source)
    at com.transbinary.imdb.backingbean.Movie.getAllMovies(Movie.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:808)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:1798)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.calculatePage(DataTable.java:768)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:153)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:79)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:401)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5049)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4884)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
    ... 88 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.init(EntityManagerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:173)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:435)
    at com.transbinary.imdb.dao.MovieManagementDaoJpaImpl.getAll(MovieManagementDaoJpaImpl.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5366)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:619)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:571)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:162)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:144)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:861)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:800)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:370)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5338)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5326)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
    ... 86 more
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It happens if you forget the persistence.xml file or if the entity is not set correctly in the file.

Comment: Its been a long time since I checked out on that project but this looks like a life saving info for me. Will drop a message whenever I checkout that project next time. Will be helpful if you could hint along the lines of issues I might be having in the persistence file or entity not correctly set as I could get the issue resolved with the 3.1.1 version of Glassfish with the same set of files. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've got my application working with Glassfish version 3.1.1. I find all three `[web, ejb, jpa]` engines working just fine with this version of Glassfish. At least for now its working and I am able to talk to database. I changed my Glassfish version from 3.1 to 3.1.1 and configured resources using Glassfish Admin Console.

I needed to add `mysql-connector-java-5.1.15-bin.jar` for server to connect to MySql 5.5 which I did not have to do with Glassfish 3.1 version. Also, `gf-client.jar` for 3.1.1 version is in the `${GLASSFISH_HOME}/lib` directory but not in `${GLASSFISH_HOME}/modules`.

I am not sure if it was a bug in Glassfish 3.1.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've got the same problem started to occur even with Glassfish 3.1.1 version :(

Comment: I uninstalled Glassfish 3.1.1 by removing the Glassfish directory and then re-installed it and then configured all the resources from scratch but nothing really seems to work. I think its a bug already reported with a different version of it but same basic problem of `EntityManagerFactory` not being able to open up to provide any `EntityManager` instances. http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17295 shows the reported issue.

Comment: I've got it working alright now. `[jpa]` engine has got itself listed with `[web, ejb]` engine and its letting my application talk to database without any problem. I did nothing to get it working. It just started working. I got up, autodeployed it and it just got the `[jpa]` engine working this time.

Comment: any idea what caused it? I have this problem myself, and it is not happening with Glassfish 2...

Comment: @oligofren: I got fortunate to get it working after several uninstalling and installation. Had to remove the whole installation directory and start from scratch and then had to configure JDBC and other resources all over again n again. Fortunately it is still working but everytime I deploy/redeploy/autodeploy my application to Glassfish 3.1 I keep my fingers crossed.