# Entity Beans : Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javabeans, netbeans-7

This is my first attempt at Entity beans and I repeatedly get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
```

I wrote a simple entity beans example using a Netbeans 7.3 and GlassFish 3.1.2.2 Server. It seems there is a problem with my persistance.xml file. However, I am unable to fix this. I read up

[JavaEE 6: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647309/javaee-6-java-lang-illegalstateexception-unable-to-retrieve-entitymanagerfacto)

[Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null for simple EJB](http://javakenai-dev.cognisync.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/unable-retrieve-entitymanagerfactory-unitname-null-simple-ejb-0)   - see nosferatum answer

But after hours also I have not quite been able to fix this. I am attaching the screenshot of my directory structure and also code for my XML file with the hope that someone can point out the mistake.

persistance.xml : ( Code autogenerated by NetBeans )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="EnterpriseApplication3-ejbPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>TestDatabase</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

[image: Project Directory Structure ( Persistance.xml autoplaced by NetBeans]

Failing Code  :

Declaration :

```
// This injects the default entity manager factory
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Point of Invocation :

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

Also, a few people seem to do this :

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPU")
```

and have the same name in the persistance.xml. I did a quick search of all my project files and did not come up with the @PersistenceContext annotation. But I added

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "EnterpriseApplication3-ejbPU")
```

to my code that calls the EntityManagerFactory. But still no success :(

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EnterpriseApplication3-ejbPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```